# How to write PrinceXML file to server using PHP

Tags: php, princexml

Trying to fwrite the pdf results from PrinceXML to the server (in a new pdf file) instead of exporting via headers to acrobat. The below code displays the results on the browser.

```
require_once("../library/Prince/prince.php");
$princeSettings = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap') >getOption('prince');
$prince = new Prince($princeSettings['path']);
$prince->setHTML(true);
$result = $prince->convert_string_to_passthru($this->htmlView);

$fp = fopen("./files/reports/report.pdf", "w");
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out for anyone who want to know...

```
require_once("../library/Prince/prince.php"); 
$princeSettings =$this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOption('prince'); 
$prince = new Prince($princeSettings['path']); $prince->setHTML(true); 
$pdfPath =realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public/files/reports/report.pdf");
$prince->convert_string_to_file($this->htmlView, $pdfPath);
```